# How to access to an enviroment variable in vercel.json?

Tags: vercel

I need to protect a value on my vercel.json file, so want to set up in an environment variable and use it on vercel.json

I set an environment variable ALLOW_ORIGIN in Vercel page > settings > environment variables, and I've tried to access in this way in my vercel.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "index.js",
        "use": "@now/node"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "headers": [
          { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "${ALLOW_ORIGIN}" },
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Did you add ALLOW_ORIGIN and value in vercel environment and tried publishing it ? should get access to it. Env files will not work when published to vercel.

Comment: yes, I added on settings > environment variables

Comment: Here's the correct way to do it with vercel (to access the env variables in the vercel environment)

in summary use @ instead of ${}

Comment: correct code:


    {
      "version": 2,
      "builds": [
        {
          "src": "index.js",
          "use": "@now/node"
        }
      ],
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "/",
          "headers": [
            { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "@ALLOW_ORIGIN" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }